# entity framework 4.5 fill and update in same context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-4.5

I am using EF 4.5 and have to fetch some records and update a flag of the fetched record. Can I do this in same context?

```
using (var context = new MyDBEntities())
{
   var qry = from a in context.Table1
             select a;
   foreach(var item in qry)
   {
        // Logic to fill custom entity (DTO) from qry
        item.Fetched = 2; // Changing the status of fetched records in DB
        context.Table1.Add(item);
   }
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can. You have to, even. The context must have the objects you modify in its change tracker. That's what happens in the query (`qry`). Then you modify them, the change tracker detects changes when `SaveChanges()` is called and update statements are generated and send to the database.

The only thing is, you should *not* do

```
context.Table1.Add(item);
```

because that creates new `Table1` records, it does not update the existing ones. Just remove the statement.

(By the way, there are other ways to make a context start change tracking, viz. *attaching* or *adding* objects to a context).